# Mystery at Stargazer's Manor: Doable with only 2 players?

Tags: escape-the-room

My SO got me Escape the Room: Mystery at Stargazer's Manor with the intent we could do it together but didn't see the game was labeled for 3+.

Without spoilers, was wondering if anyone who played this thinks it could be done with 2 players or if I should follow the box advice for maximum fun.

From light reading (again avoiding spoilers), I expect this is a one shot, so am seeking advice rather than trying and seeing=)

Comment: More players just gives you more eyes/brains to observe and solve the puzzles. This one was relatively easy for 4 of us, and we finished in about a half hour.

Comment: All that to say, I'd go for it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, Escape the Room: Mystery at Stargazer's Manor can be played with any number of players, even one.

With that said, I would recommend 2-4 players. As with most escape room-type games, the more the merrier, although there is only so much physical material to pass around between players.

**Source:** personal experience™

Comment: I accepted this answer because after playing this I agree with it.  We disclaimer however played this with 5.  There is a chart in the game that gives times for what size group.  I assume you could use the "3" for 2 player or add more (or just whatever, no-one is judging you).  Thanks!